# How can I solve [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-modules, adonis.js, node-redis

I want to run a project with adonis 4.1 in my local. So I run `adonis serve --dev`

It show :

```
 SERVER STARTED 
> Watching files for changes...

info: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:3333
```

If http://127.0.0.1:3333 called, there exist error like this ::

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)
```

This seems the problem in redis. How can I solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks